# ssh over wifi vs broadband weirdness

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-note, ssh, terminal

I have a really weird issue with connecting to an outside host from my android device (2.3.6) using ssh. I have no problem with connectbot actually, but when working on a terminal the weirdness kicks in. I've tried several solutions (terminal-ide, rsync4android, kbox) and the symptoms are all the same.

If I'm connected to the net through the broadband link everything works find, host resolution, ssh, etc.

However if I'm connected through my home wifi router host resolution doesn't work and neither does ssh (connectbot still works over wifi, but none of the terminal based solutions). It simply hangs when I do "ssh host.com" or "ssh x.y.z.v" so it doesn't matter if I use IP numbers or the domain name.

I thought this has to do with the firewall setup on my wifi router, but on my laptop everything is working without a problem, I can ssh to any host, etc, and on the laptop the connection is also through the wifi router.

So to summarize this is situation:

1. connectbot on device: works with both wifi and broadband
2. terminal/ssh on device: only works with broadband
3. terminal/ssh on laptop: works with wifi

I should add that ping, wget, netcat, etc. all work from the terminal to the outside host also on wifi so the problem is ssh-specific.

What can be the reason? Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Unfortunately strace or the -v and -vv options for the ssh client are not available on android, so I'm really at a loss how to debug this.

In case you are interested why I don't simply use connectbot and forget about the terminals: I'd like to use rsync eventually which would operate over ssh.

Comment: can you ping the hosts by numeric IP addresses (within your wifi network) from within the terminal on your device? If yes, then can you ping to outside hosts on the terminal?

Comment: Yes, I can ping all hosts from the terminal. Also, the outside host which runs the ssh server also runs a web server and I can fetch any content with wget. So the problem is really ssh-specific.

Comment: What does the log say when performing ssh....? Is it authentication, no ssh keys...? More information? :)

Comment: It just hangs, there is no output at all. And since there is no strace I don't know how to find out what the problem is.

Comment: use `ssh -v` for verbose output, add an extra `v` to the switch for more verbose output.

Comment: Unfortunately the -v or -vv options are not recognized by ssh on android.

Comment: Care to be more specific on what is the ssh app? There's a few out there... I use sshdroid pro... try switching to another ssh app?

Comment: It's the ssh client that comes with terminal-ide: http://code.google.com/p/terminal-ide/ It's actually dropbear: https://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/dropbear.html

Comment: Since I use terminal-ide for all sorts of things and it works with the broadband link I really would like to make it work also with the wifi link. That's the reason I wouldn't want to switch ssh clients.

Comment: maybe its not ssh but terminal-ide which is a *terminal IDE is a command line java / android dev kit that runs on the device itself.* It may not know anything/zero awareness of ssh? Have you thought of that?

Comment: As I've said ssh works perfectly well from terminal-ide if I'm connected through the broadband link.